# Why does my SQL while(set.next()) skips the first element?

Tags: java, mysql, loops, jdbc

I execute:

```
select * from table_name order by column desc;
```

And I want to go through the items sequentially. I got the `ResultSet` from that and did:

```
while(set.next()) {
    // processing code
}
```

Unfortunately, that skips the very first element. What's the best way to iterate through the entire `ResultSet` and include the very first element?

Comment: Are you sure of what you are asking? I have always used the set = stmt.executeQuery() and then the while(set.next()){ set.getString("COLUMN"); } and I never missed a result.

Comment: You should provide more context (more code). It looks like you are calling `next()` at least once before the loop.

Comment: You must have already advanced the set in other code. There is nothing wrong with the code in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
set.beforeFirst();
while(set.next()) {
    // Your code
}
```

This will run the body of your loop once before advancing the `ResultSet`. You don't want to use a `do` loop (my previous answer) because it will throw an Exception if the query has 0 rows returned.

Comment: Thank you, that was one of the solutions I had in mind but I wanted an opinion from other coders :)

Comment: If the query gave no results the code inside the block (normally getting something from the ResultSet) will give an exception.

Comment: There is no need to do a set.beforeFirst() for the reasons I stated in my answer and because the beforeFirst can throw exceptions (see the Documentation).

Comment: @gfelisberto It shouldn't be necessary, but according to him, it is necessary. Maybe he's calling `next()` somewhere else. I'm not sure

Comment: I've got 'Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY'
However when I just use "while(rs.next)" it skips the first row...

Answer (score 7):

I know this is really old but my search hit here and after the solution didn't work for me (forward only result set) I believe the issue was never really addressed. In my case, I was doing:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rs -> {
    while(rs.next()) {
        // processRow
    }
    // no return statement
, args);
```

I then looked more closely at the method that was being called and the second argument was a "RowCallbackHandler" and not a "ResultSetExtractor" so the correct use of this code is:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rs -> {
    // processRow
}, args);
```

This does the "while (rs.next())" loop for you.
I'd wager the OP was doing the same thing I was.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct and you are not loosing any records. In the SDK Documentation for [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) you can read that:

*"A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. **Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.** The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set."*

Only case were you could loose records if you do a resultSet.next() before the one you are showing.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever next() is called, it reads a record from result set.

```
if (!set.next() ) {
    System.out.println("no data");
} else {

    do {
        //statement(s)
    } while (resultSet.next());
}
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting that he call `System.out.println`? This could be called in the middle of a much larger app that doesn't use the console for anything?

Comment: You are right! That's the place for the programmer to add Exception statements! In case of enterprise application, it has to be logged somewhere.